# Sort Array of Dates / Console bug?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm confused why the console is showing me a sorted array at both logs. Because at the first point where I'm logging it shouldn't be sorted?

```
  static reloadAndSortItems() {
    let array = [];
    const items = Store.getStoredItems();

    items.forEach(function (item) {

      // getting the stored date --> back to date object

      let episodeDate = Date.parse(item.episode);
      let parsedEpisode = new Date(episodeDate);


      array.push(parsedEpisode);



    });

    **// should not sorted at this point
    console.log('not sorted', array);**



    let tested = array.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a - b
    });
    **// should be sorted array at this point
    console.log('sorted', tested);**





  }
```

this is the array that is coming in ( which is out of order) :

```
["2018-09-13T00:30:00.000Z","2018-09-14T05:25:00.000Z","2018-09-13T00:30:00.000Z","2018-09-11T01:30:00.000Z","2018-09-11T01:30:00.000Z"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [**`sort()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method mutates the initial array, and also returns a new one, so finally you will get two arrays with the same order of elements:

```js
let arr = [1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 7];
let result = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log('Original:', arr);
console.log('Final:', result);
```

To avoid such behavior, you can create additional array (for example, using [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, it returns a new array and doesn't mutate the original one), and use it as your initial array:

```js
let arr = [1, 6, 2, 9, 3, 7];
let duplicate = arr.map(d => d);
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log('Sorted:', arr);
console.log('Duplicate of the initial array:', duplicate);
```

Answer (score 1):

[The `sort()` method mutates the array it's called on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), so the correct thing to do here is to log to console the `array` variable, rather than the `tested` variable:

```
static reloadAndSortItems() {
    let array = [];
    const items = Store.getStoredItems();

    items.forEach(function (item) {

      // getting the stored date --> back to date object

      let episodeDate = Date.parse(item.episode);
      let parsedEpisode = new Date(episodeDate);    

      array.push(parsedEpisode);    
    });

    array.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a - b
    });

    console.log('sorted', array);    
  }
```

Alternativly, you could clone the `array` variable by means of `.map()`, and then call the `.sort()` method on that cloned array, like so:

```
static reloadAndSortItems() {
    let array = [];
    const items = Store.getStoredItems();

    items.forEach(function (item) {

      // getting the stored date --> back to date object

      let episodeDate = Date.parse(item.episode);
      let parsedEpisode = new Date(episodeDate);    

      array.push(parsedEpisode);    
    });

    // Copy/clone the array using map into tested variable
    const tested = array.map(function(item) { return item; });

    // Sort the tested array. Calling sort on tested will leave array unaffected
    tested.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a - b
    });

    console.log('sorted', tested);  // Sorted
    console.log('array', array);    // Unsorted
  }
```